# Is it possible to speed up adding of a set of elements to DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, gwt, batch-processing

I have a container widget which is updated very often. When some event comes, I need to append a child to container, or remove one of its children. Think of this as of a list of chat participants which listens for the event of joining/leaving the chat.

If the number of children is really big (several hundreds) along with big number of events  arriving, the drawing of DOM starts to slow down. User notices delays. I.e. adding/removing of sub-element to container starts takes more and more time.

How can I speed up this process?

**I think of using a kind of a 'batch update' technique, well-known from database applications.** Indeed, if I would collect events of updating my list and run the list of updates one time in a second - will this speed up my computations? In fact the number of widgets to add would not change, but probably by running this task one by one I can get the 'batch' effect somehow?

This is just a guess.

I am using GWT, but its not the point. Execution is especially slow in IE8, but my question is cross-browser.

Comment: Show some basic code of how you find, remove, add.

Answer (score 1):

Set display:none for container before adding children. you can set it back to its original state after